# How to 'Add active class to the current button'

Tags: javascript

I have the below code on a page on a shopify website, but the buttons wont change color when active. Seems to work fine when I try it on bootply but wont work withen shopify.
The error I see in the console is Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null""

```
<script>
  filterSelection("all")
  function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
      if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
  }

  function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) { element.className += " " + arr2[i]; }
    }
  }

  function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
        arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
      }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
  }


  // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
  var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
  var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
      current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
      this.className += " active";
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: probably `var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");` is causing error. Check if `btnContainer` has value

Comment: modern day browsers have classList.add/remove()

Comment: @NidhinJoseph How would I check if btnContainer has a value?

Comment: a simple if condition would do `if(btnContainer ) {var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");}`

Comment: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Place class assigning code here
});` - Its better to wait for DOM to completely load all elements - And then do manipulations over that

Comment: @user2932057 That's it! Thanks a lot. I would like to mark your answer as the correct one.
Would you happen to also know why the "all" filter does not work while the others work fine? Actually on page load the "all" button shows nothing, but if I go another button and come back to the "all" button it then shows correctly

Comment: @vermit25 -  Place filter selection function call also inside DOM Load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to wait for DOM to completely load all elements - do manipulations after that

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {  
// Place class assigning code here 
 // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
 var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
 var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
btns[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
});
}
// Place filter selection also inside DOM Load
filterSelection("all");
});
```

Comment: Thank You! Your edit helped with the all filter as well, much appreciated.